# How to change a variable in price-bundle.js?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In `Magento/Bundle/view/base/web/js/price-bundle.js`

I want to change the globalOptions variable:

```
var globalOptions = {
    optionConfig: null,
    productBundleSelector: 'input.bundle.option, select.bundle.option, textarea.bundle.option',
    qtyFieldSelector: 'input.qty',
    priceBoxSelector: '.price-box',
    optionHandlers: {},
    optionTemplate: '<%- data.label %>' +
    '<% if (data.finalPrice.value) { %>' +
    ' +<%- data.finalPrice.formatted %>' +
    '<% } %>',
    controlContainer: 'dd', // should be eliminated
    priceFormat: {},
    isFixedPrice: false
};
```

How d you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object `globalOptions` used as default options in `Magento/Bundle/view/base/web/js/price-bundle.js`.

```
$.widget('mage.priceBundle', {
    options: globalOptions,
    //.....
```

---

You can add mixin and extend default options.

*requirejs-config.js*

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Bundle/js/price-bundle': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/bundle/price-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

*Vendor_Module/view/base/web/js/bundle/price-mixin.js*

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (priceBundle) {

        $.widget('mage.priceBundle', priceBundle, {
            options: {
                isFixedPrice: true
            }
        });

        return $.mage.priceBundle;
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, got another issue now where one of the functions needs to be modified